# Java set iteration in range

Tags: java, set

I want to iterate over java set by providing some range. like I can do it for list..

```
//for list
int startRange=3;
int endRange = 5; 
List list = myList();
for (int i=startRange;i<endRange;i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

Now I wanted to iterate on below java set like above in startRange and endRange

```
Set<String> set = new java.util.HashSet<String>(list);
```

Thanks.

Comment: `HashSet` is not ordered...

Comment: @alfasin is correct; `List` encompasses a total ordering on its elements, but `HashSet` has no such thing... PS you should use `List.listIterator` in your original code.

Comment: Assuming you want to remove duplicates in a list by wrapping it in a set object, you can get back the list using `List<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>(set);` and iterate through that, right?

Comment: Or, he can do `set.toArray()` and iterate the array. But still, the order here has no meaning...

Comment: Your exact requirements are unclear, so I don’t know whether it will help you to do `Set<String> set = new java.util.HashSet<>(list.subList(startRange, endRange));` to obtain a set consisting of only the elements in the range. Now you can iterate over this set.

Comment: Do you want to iterate over the same elements as in the list example? And if so, why not just use the list example? Or do you want to iterate over elements 3 to 5 in the order the `HashSet.iterator()` returns them (which is different from the order you get them from the list’s iterator)? And if so, why, what is the point? I’m sure you have a valid reason, and we could help you better if you told us.

Answer (score 3):

```
int count =0, min= 3 , max = 5;
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>();

Iterator<String> itr  = s.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()) {
    if ( count > min && count < max ) {
        //Do something
    }
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`LinkedHashSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html) and maintain the order.

Comment: This still doesn't provide him anything of much use. `LinkedHashSet` exposes the same functionality as `HashSet`, only its `iterator` uses insertion-order.

Answer (score 0):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444673/java-set-iteration-in-range#comment16733378_12444673) below.

> @alfasin is correct; `List` encompasses a total ordering on its elements, but `HashSet` has no such thing... PS you should use `List.listIterator` in your original code.

That being said, there is something similar for other kinds of `Set`s that *do* impose a total order --  [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)s. There exists an analogous [`subSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#subSet(E,%20E)), as well as [`headSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#headSet(E)) and [`tailSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html#tailSet(E)) which have similar functions. These also exist in [`NavigableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html) along with other methods like [`ceiling`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#ceiling(E)), [`floor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NavigableSet.html#floor(E)), etc.

Note that the orders here are not that much alike. `List` order is essentially arbitrary, whatever the user intended, while `SortedSet`s order using a comparison sort.

Answer (score 0):

Set is not ordered use [Class LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html)

Comment: Thanks all.It worked.I was looking for what @Vikdor described.

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can change the Set to Array and then iterate over a range.

Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
         set.add(i);
    }
Object[] array = set.toArray();


for (Integer i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.print(array[i] + " ,");
    }
```